# Create a macro in Google Sheets using Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform

I want to programmatically create a macro and call the same from another stand-alone app script project.

One of the approaches I have used is to create the project using the [projects.create](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/create) API and called the function in that project using [scripts.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/scripts/run).

The problem with this approach is that I've to manually set the GCP project for the newly created project, as the script and calling application must share the same GCP project as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute#requirements).
I couldn't find any resource to perform it programmatically.

**Basically, I want to execute the App script code provided by the user dynamically from my existing Google Sheets add-on.**

Any suggestion or help would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Publish a webapp and call the function by http post?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand correctly, but lets assume you want to do the following:

1. Create a Function (your Macro) in a Apps Script Project
2. Use the Function in the above Project from multiple Google Spreadsheets

In that case you can do multiple things, my suggestions would be

1. Create a Apps Script Project
2. Enter your Function (your Macro) in that Project
3. Use that Project as a Library
4. Wherever (in a Spreadsheet) you need this Function (your Macro), add the Library and create a Function which calls the Library Function.

One alternative, if you really want a App which runs as Addon, then [see here the reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/editors/sheets) for that.

#### Reference

- [Library](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries)